# fancy-preview with other \ref-like commands (such as \autoref and \cref)

Tags: cross-referencing, preview, fancytooltips

I finally got `fancy-preview` working, and I found the place (around line 97) in the script to add to the list of environments which it catches (to add propositions and so on).  But what I can't find after a quick read-through is a way to have `fancy-preview` pick up `\autoref`, `\cref`, and other `\ref`-like commands.  Does anybody know how to do this?  (I don't know perl or low-level latex, so I could have easily missed something obvious.)

I much prefer using `\autoref` to `\ref`.  After spending way too much time setting up `fancy-preview`, it would be pretty disappointing to have to give up `\autoref` to use it.

EDIT: After looking into this a bit further, I don't think this is controlled in the `fancy-preview` script.  I think it's in the actual `fancytooltips.dtx`, around line 756.  I don't yet know how to adjust this code to also redefine `\autoref`, but I think I'm at least looking in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me. Save as `file.tex` and compile by `fancy-preview file`

Explanation:

- In `fancytooltips.sty` the original command `\ref` is saved into `\fancy@oldref` and replaced by a command which acts like `\ref` and adds the tooltip.
- Similarly, we store the comand `\autoref` to `\oldautoref` and replace it by a command which acts like old `\autoref`, ant then acts like `\ref` but the referrence is not printed (`\fancy@oldref` is temporarily redefined) and only the tooltip remains.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\oldautoref\autoref
\def\autoref#1{\oldautoref{#1}{\def\fancy@oldref##1{}\ref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{sec:1}
Consider equation
\begin{equation}\label{equation}
  x^2+y^2=\frac 1\pi
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,fill=blue] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Caption of the figure}
  \label{figure}
\end{figure}


\section{Second}\label{sec:2}
This if the second section. It follows Section \ref{sec:1}. See also
\autoref{equation} and \autoref{figure}, i.e. eq. \eqref{equation} and
Picture \ref{figure}.
\end{document}
```